# how to make INTO keyword work on all data types

Tags: mysql

In my stored procedure:

```
DECLARE execution_time DATETIME;
SELECT `Execution_Time`
FROM `orders`
WHERE `ID` = 1
INTO execution_time;
```

It seems that this query does not work except if `Execution_Time` and execution_time are integers. They don't seem to work if both are `varchars` or `datetime`. `execution_time` remains `NULL`.

Is there a specific way to make it work on other data types rather than only integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work for strings, numbers, and dates.  I'm pretty sure the problem is confusion between a column and a variable.  You can try:

```
DECLARE v_execution_time DATETIME;
SELECT `Execution_Time`
FROM `orders`
WHERE `ID` = 1
INTO v_execution_time;
```

Or, what I would likely do:

```
DECLARE @execution_time DATETIME;
SELECT @execution_time := o.Execution_Time
FROM orders o
WHERE o.ID = 1;
```

I think `into` exists for (sort of) compatibility with Oracle.  MySQL has simpler ways to assign variables.

Comment: I'm never use into at end select, both syntax are correct.

Answer (score -1):

Read about [select ... into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html). You should write into clause before from...
for your example:

```
DECLARE execution_time2 DATETIME;
SELECT `Execution_Time`
INTO execution_time2
FROM `orders`
WHERE `ID` = 1;
```

and "A local variable should not have the same name as a table column" read about [Local Variable Scope and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html)

Comment: I didn't downvote.  But according to the syntax diagram for `SELECT`, this is not true:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html.  Either version is acceptable.

Comment: sorry, you have right Gordon, "The exception is that the INTO clause can appear either as shown in the syntax description or immediately following the select_expr list.", please edit your answer some how, than i will correct my vote